# How can `cat` read a file without a file descriptor?

Tags: linux, cat, proc, vfs

I'm learning Linux `procfs`, which utilizes a virtual file system where operations like `open`, `read`, `write`, and `release` are processed by functions registered to it.

I've left the `open` and `release` to null pointer by mistake, and when I try to read the content of the file, with Python codes like:

```py
with open("/proc/testfile", "r") as f:
    content = f.read()
```

The program stuck and I read error from the kernel dmesg that null pointer is dereferenced, which is expected, as `open` is pointed to NULL.

However, the `cat` command from GNU coreutils can do the job, giving me output like

```bsh
$ cat /proc/testfile
testoutput
```

which means that `cat` have not invoked the `open` function but directly invoking `read` (`write` can also be done).

In my understanding, `open()` will return a file descriptor which is further be used to deal with files, and `read()` requires a file descriptor to continue.

How is this be done inside `cat`?

Comment: What happens if you do that with `/proc/cpuinfo`? It is not clear how `testfile` got there. A setup that can be reproduced will help everybody help you.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani it’s not explicit in the question, but I gather that `testfile` comes from victrid’s own addition to `/proc`.

Comment: Hmm, it might be useful here to look inside the kernel module and see what it does. I can't remember what debugging tools there are for kernel development (and how easy they are to use), but you could e.g. just print some log messages from _all_ of your functions to see what exactly gets called. Still doesn't explain why the exact same `open()`/`openat()`+`read()` combo would work from `cat` and not from `python`. But assuming they work the same on your system for other files, the answer must be in your module, _somehow_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `strace` to see what system call some command is making:

```
$ strace cat /proc/version
[...]
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/version", O_RDONLY) = 3
[...]
read(3, "Linux version 5.16.0-5-amd64 (de"..., 131072) = 181
write(1, "Linux version 5.16.0-5-amd64 (de"..., 181)   = 181
[...]
```

```
$ strace python3 -c 'open("/proc/version")'
[...]
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/version", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
[...]
```

Appart for that `O_CLOEXEC` flag which should not have any bearing to your issue, both make the exact same system call on my system.